# Angular jsonp.get: rejected although status code 200 Ok

Tags: rest, angular, typescript, http-status-code-200

I'm trying to call my simple web api developed in Jersey, which results in:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Facebook",
        "userName": "abc@gmail.com",
        "password": "Qwerty@123"
    }
]
```

My jsonp get request looks like this:

```
this.jsonp.get('http://localhost:8080/api/rest/domains?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK')
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => console.log("Success: " + response),
                err => console.log("Failed: " + err));
```

However, I'm getting following message printed in console:

> Failed: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL:
>   [http://localhost:8080/DomainServiceApi/rest/domains?callback=**ng_jsonp**.__req0.finished](http://localhost:8080/DomainServiceApi/rest/domains?callback=__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished)

I can't figure out what is wrong with this.

**EDIT:**  Finally my problem got solved. I returned back to using http.get method. Then on removing my now useless in memory web api imports, I got the error message that "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" should be included in my headers in the response on server side. So I included this header in my Jersey web api and everything is working fine.

If anyone is using Jersey, read [How to add headers in Jersey response](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/).

Comment: Please don't include real passwords and/or usernames in your questions

Comment: @devqon. It's not my real password. Though I changed the username. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Angular 1.x (the `angularjs` tag) or Angular 2.x (the `angular2` tag)?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm using angular 2

Answer (score 1):

200 is just the GET response which are coming through server .(Server sent the json) But i guess the json request is not formatted well . Can you please look into the json request if its well formatted . Can you please post you json here . Please let me know if its works .

Comment: I am also guessing that this might be related with the format of my json. I have already posted my json above in the question. Are you asking for something else. * That is the response I'm getting in postman.

Comment: I think api you are hitting doesn't support JSONP. Can you please look into this way.

Comment: See in console you will find url like this :-

Comment: http://localhost:9090/api/rest/domains?callback=angular.callbacks._0, 
http://localhost:9090/api/rest/domains?callback=angular.callbacks._1

Hit your server , you will get 404 error , so its error and going to print inside error code..May be its a reason .

Comment: My api doesn't support Jsonp. Previously I thought it doesn't matter. Recently I came to know that the api should also support Jsonp explicitly.